# MYSQL sequence of orders by customer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query and what I would like to do is add a column that will identify what order this is for a distinct customer. entity_id is unique per order, so really all I want to do is number unique entity_id for each customer ordered by created_at.

First order=1

second order=2

third order=3
.....

I would appreciate any help as I don't really know how to do this efficiently.

```
SELECT 
        sfo.created_at AS "Order Date",
        sfo.entity_id AS "Order ID",
        left(sfoi.sku,3) AS "SKU",
        sfoi.qty_ordered,   
        sfo.customer_email AS "Customer Email",     
        sfo.customer_firstname AS "Customer Firstname",     
        sfo.Customer_lastname AS "Customer Lastname"
    from sales_flat_order sfo, sales_flat_order_item sfoi, sales_flat_order_address sfoa        
    where       
      sfoi.order_id = sfo.entity_id AND     
      sfoa.entity_id = sfo.billing_address_id
```

EDIT: ADDED DATA AFTER BELOW ANSWER

```
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','2.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','2.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','2'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','2.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','3'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','2.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','4'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','2.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','5'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','103','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','6'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','7'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','8'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','9'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','10'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','11'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','105','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','12'
'2015-04-13 17:45:15','20537','105','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','13'
'2015-04-13 17:45:15','20537','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','14'
'2015-04-13 17:45:15','20537','201','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','15'
'2015-04-13 17:45:15','20537','201','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','16'
'2015-04-29 14:42:28','22212','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','17'
'2015-05-11 17:11:22','23301','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','18'
```

This is the desired results

```
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','2.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','2.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','2.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','2.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','2.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','103','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','201','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-01 14:48:13','19406','105','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','1'
'2015-04-13 17:45:15','20537','105','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','2'
'2015-04-13 17:45:15','20537','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','2'
'2015-04-13 17:45:15','20537','201','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','2'
'2015-04-13 17:45:15','20537','201','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','2'
'2015-04-29 14:42:28','22212','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','3'
'2015-05-11 17:11:22','23301','102','1.0000','test@google.com','joe','vers','4'
```

So in this example all the rows with entity_id 19406 should all have the seqnum of 1 and 20537 should be 2 and so on. So if it is the same entity_id it should have the same seqnum.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Second. the easiest way to do what you want in MySQL is to use variables:

```
select sfo.created_at AS "Order Date", sfo.entity_id AS "Order ID",
       left(sfoi.sku,3) AS "SKU", sfoi.qty_ordered,   
       sfo.customer_email AS "Customer Email",     
       sfo.customer_firstname AS "Customer Firstname",     
       sfo.Customer_lastname AS "Customer Lastname",
       (@rn := if(@e = sfo.customer_email, @rn + 1,
                  if(@e := sfo.customer_email, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as seqnum
from sales_flat_order sfo join
     sales_flat_order_item sfoi
     on sfoi.order_id = sfo.entity_id join
     sales_flat_order_address sfoa        
     on sfoa.entity_id = sfo.billing_address_id cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @e := '') params
order by sfo.customer_email, created_at;
```

Note:  This assumes that `customer_email` defines the customer.

Comment: This works great but it is numbering them not quite right because there is a row for each item ordered. So entity_id or created_at needs to be incorporated so it will only increase the seqnum if the entity_id changes.

Comment: How would not increment seqnum unless the entity_id has changed? So if the entity_id is the same it have the same seqnum, because there is multiple rows for each entity_id but they are the same order.

Comment: @llerdal . . . This logic uses `customer_email`.  You can use `entity_id` instead of the email in the `order by` and variable expression.

Comment: . . That doesnt work there is multiple rows per entity_id and it numbers them different when they should all be the same. So if the entity_id is the same it has the same seqnum.

Comment: @llerdal . . . Can you ask another question with sample data and desired results?

Comment: . . I added some data to the question above.